# Spring-boot Spring-security Freemarker login success 404 error

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, freemarker

I am using Spring boot + spring security + Freemarker.

I have a 2 part question.

1. I have trouble with CSRF token injected into my page. I think i do not get it because i cannot use form:form tag in freemarker.
2. If i Disable csrf, it takes me to a 404 page after success login.

I think i am wrong somewere in config

Code copied below

Application.java

```
@ComponentScan("in.co.mmbf.loanstar")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class).run(args);
  }


  @Override
  protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
      return application.sources(Application.class);
  }
}
```

ApplicationConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    //registry.addRedirectViewController("/", "home");
    registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.addViewController("/error").setViewName("error");
    registry.addViewController("/admin").setViewName("admin");
}


@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig() throws IOException, TemplateException {
    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory factory = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactory();
    factory.setTemplateLoaderPaths(new String[]{"classpath:org/springframework/web/servlet/view/freemarker/", "classpath:/templates/", "/templates"});
    factory.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
    factory.setPreferFileSystemAccess(false);
    FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    result.setConfiguration(factory.createConfiguration());
    return result;
}
}
```

ApplicationSecurity.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/", "/resources/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and()
    .logout()
        .permitAll();
}

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
  web.ignoring().antMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/img/**", "favicon.ico");
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").password("password").roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
    if (roles.contains("ADMIN")){
        response.sendRedirect("/Admin");
        return;
    }
    response.sendRedirect("/home");
}
}
```

login.ftl

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MMBF Loan Star - Login</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom/login.css">
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring/>
</head>
<body onload="document.loginForm.username.focus();">

 <div id="fullscreen_bg" class="fullscreen_bg"></div>

 <div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin" name="loginForm" action="/loanstar/login" method="post">
   <h1 class="form-signin-heading text-muted">Sign In</h1>
   <#if RequestParameters.error??>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" align="center">
      <strong>Invalid Login!</strong><br>Invalid username or password
    </div>
   <#elseif RequestParameters.logout??>
    <div class="alert alert-info" align="center">
      <strong>Logged out!</strong><br>You have Logged out of Loanstar
    </div>
   </#if>
   
   <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus> 
   <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
   <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>
  </form>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

home.ftl

```html
<#import "/layout/defaultLayout.ftl" as layout>
<@layout.pagelayout title="Home">
  <div><h1>Hello Dude</h1></div>
</@layout.pagelayout>
```

application.properties

```
server.contextPath=/loanstar
#security.basic.enabled=false
spring.mvc.favicon.enabled=false
spring.freemarker.template-loader-path=/
spring.freemarker.suffix=.ftl
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [PR](https://github.com/toocoolblue2000/mmbf/pull/1), it can login success, and redirect to home successfully.

But you'd better to separate the success handler in another class, not in config.

And about the tags issue please see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/907)

Comment: Awesome, Worked like a charm. Thanks @chaoluo.

For others, Here is where i went wrong:

I had to add a successHandler in my ApplicationSecurity.java

.loginPage("/login").successHandler(this)

and 

 if (roles.contains("ADMIN")){
         redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/admin");
//            response.sendRedirect("/Admin");
        } else {
         redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/home");
//         response.sendRedirect("/home");
        }